# Regular Expression for formatting a file

Tags: regex, visual-studio, regex-negation

My file has data with each line starting with a specific pattern

```
1000000179|abcd.....
1000000180|wedwedw...
1000000181|wnewedwed...
```

i've opened the file in visual studio and need an RE to find any line not beginning in the correct sequence. Like below line 3 and 4 are not valid. How to isolate them using RE

```
1000000179|abcd.....
1000000180|wedwedw...
1000xyadaa|wnewedwed...
%dfgxyadaa|wnewedwed...
```

Comment: So what is the pattern? Always "1000" followed by 6 alphanumerical and then a pipe?

Comment: pattern is 10 numerals followedby pipe

Comment: @Kent that'll detect the _correct_ lines, not the incorrect ones.

Comment: A regex for code, or a regex for Find/Replace? If the latter, what version of VS is this? Different versions have differing regex syntax.

Comment: @KennethK. need regex for find/replace. VS 2005

Comment: @Sepster yep! .. You are right. Sorry....don't know if VS editor has function/feature to select/highlight the matched lines, then you could inverse selection.. I don't even know how VS editor looks like....  0 Experience...

Comment: @Kent caps \D negates the class mate :-)

Comment: @Sepster what if there are 9 numbers+ pipe? I mean, no `\D` at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something as simple as `^[^0-9]{1,10}[^|].*$` should detect any lines that don't start with ten numerals and a pipe.

If you just want to select just the first part of the line, then `^[^0-9]{1,10}[^|]`

NB: you can replace `[^0-9]` with `\D` (case sensitive!) if you prefer that syntax, eg `^\D{1,10}[^|]`

To reverse the logic (ie find the correct lines), use `^[0-9]{10}\|.*$`  or `^\d{10}\|`

---

**EDIT: For VS2005's search/replace "regular expressions":**

To find lines that DO NOT start with 10 numerics followed by a pipe: `^~([0-9]^10\|)`

To find lines that DO start with 10 numerics followed by a pipe: `^[0-9]^10\|`

Note that the `\d` and `\D` syntax does not work, as per @KennethK.'s comment below.  The equivalent for a single digit ie `[0-9]` in VS regular expressions is `:d`.

Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(VS.80).aspx for the list of regular expressions available in VS2005.

Comment: does it work for visual studio? it is not detecting the lines beginning without 10 numerals and pipe

Comment: @mhn that's right, because you said "need an RE to find any line **NOT** beginning in the correct sequence." :-) To reverse the logic, Remove the ^ from INSIDE the square brackets, or use \d instead of \D if you're using that syntax.

Comment: no luck :( is it because i'm using visual studio? if i need to use another tool , pls suggest

Comment: The regex syntax for VS 2005 uses VS's "custom" (bleh!) syntax. It doesn't use traditional regex syntax.

Comment: Yes, but `\d` and `\D` do not  ;)  `:z` is the equivalent of `\d+` in Find/Replace.

Comment: @Sepster thanks! the tool is the culprit! ur solution works fine on notepad++. However.. i'm extending my question. The incorrect lines i have isolated are mostly those that belong to the immediate previous line. How to move them using a replace function?

Comment: @mnh I have updated my answer with the correct syntax for VS2005 too, in case you still want it ;-)  Thanks for the accept, I really appreciated it.

Comment: I'd change this part of your answer:  "There is no equivalent for a single digit ie [0-9] in VS regular expressions." The `[0-9]` itself represents a single digit, and there is also `:d` (which I couldn't recall earlier).

Comment: @KennethK. Earlier, I scanned that MSDN docco high and low looking for an equivalent (as the `:z` you suggested earlier wasn't a _single_ digit), but didn't see it.  When I read your recent post just now I figured this `:d` you've suggested must've been for eg VS2008+ and hence why I didn't see it first time.  But sure enough, it's in there too, I just missed it!  Thanks again, have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to find, try the following expression:

```
^~(1000000).*$
```

Where the `^`, `.*`, and `$` all function as in typical regex, and the `~(...)` means "not match". So the overall intent of the pattern is to find lines that do not start with the string "1000000".

Comment: As I understand it, a well-formed string must start with ten digits followed by a pipe.  (That was clarified in the comments, not in the question itself.)  The opposite of that would be `^~(:d^10\|).*$`